# How to change url of default button on drupal?

Tags: drupal

I need to change url of default button on drupal. On that button, the url is example/blog. And i want to changet it becomes example/blog/1.
[capture of my web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQyg6.jpg)

Comment: Are those blocks being rendered by drupal views?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should enable twig engine debugging(explained [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates)) to find out what *.html.twig files does it fire and then cover it with your custom file or change the original one.